# iOS - Force clear/refresh app cache programmatically and update assets

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I'm working on updating my app, and i have updated the some images, and videos (which all are stored locally in the app bundle). When I run it in the simulator and on the device it still shows the old content.

The only way to get it to show the new content is either delete the old app or restart the simulator, which both are not ideal once the app reaches the store since users will still see the old content.

I'm looking for a way to programmatically refresh/clear the cached images and videos instead of having to delete the app and install it again!

The following code will only clear the UIWebView cache, so it doesn't work!

```
[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];
```

I'm looking for a way to force clear/refresh the cache in my app delegate in order to display the new assets.

FYI, the assets have the same file name, so for example, when i replaced the logo, it still show the old one unless i delete the app and reinstall it.

Your would be appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: explain "stored locally". Are they stored in your app bundle or are they in your apps document or temp dirs?

Comment: @SamB in the app bundle. i just updated my post. thanks!

Comment: If its in your app bundle then its the first time I ever heard of this behavior. I have changed my apps multiple times with new app images and assets (keeping the name same) and they get picked up right away. There is no such "clear cache" for iOS app bundle resources. Most likely there is some sort of problem with your Xcode project where it is still looking at old resources. Check your Xcode and see if there are build warnings for that

Comment: @SamB I've updated other apps in the past and never saw that issue before! Once i deleted the app and install it again i see all the new assets and everything is the way it should be.